# How do find if a control is a listbox using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listbox

I have a dynamic aspx pages where asp.net controls will be enabled and disabled. 
I am checking what kind of controls are present so that i can validate. 
i can check wether a controls is a checkbox or radiobutton but how can i check if it is a listbox.

i am trying this but not working any help

```
  if (control.is('input[type="radio"]')) {
                         alert("radiobuttonlist");
                     }

  if (control.is('input[type="option"]')) {
                         alert("listbox");
                     }
```

the listbox one is not working how to check if there is a control listbox type

Comment: `option` is not an input element type. Your selector should probably just be `option` or `select`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
control.is('select[multiple]')
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you're looking for

```
control.is('input[type="option"]')
```

Input elements don't have this kind of type.

Maybe you could look for

```
control.is("option")
```

Elements

Here you go 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/scXuH/108/)

Since you are selecting all the inputs in your $().each because the select is not an input it was not selected by jQuery I changed a little bit the .each() and I evaluated to search it the current object was a select.

Comment: In your code control.is('input[type="radio"]') evaluates to true? right, the thing here is that an input cannot be of type "option". Could you add some code of the example html that you want to check if it exist to see if I can help you

Comment: I added a fiddle with some changes.

Comment: can you post the link to your fiddle..i don't see any change in my fiddle